# Using an array in a Where clause

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

So what I need to do is find in my tables where id = id **and** name = name. I have tried this with no success.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $mysqltable WHERE id='$id' && name='$name'"
```

EDIT I found that I was missing a } bracket below this and the above code does work :/ Thank you everyone.

Comment: Have you verified that the generated query works at all? what does `echo $sql` produce? Have you run the query with `mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error())` to trap any error messages?

Comment: I have an there are no errors.

Comment: Is $id and $name an array? If so, you'll need to loop trough foreach.

Comment: @TylerRadlick Where is the array here?

Comment: @JonathanSampson I thought maybe I would need one as I have never performed this action with php before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i would have done it: Also try entering the table name instead of a variable.

```
$sql = "SELECT * From $mysqltable WHERE id='$id' AND name='$name'";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Just a note for anyone looking AND and && are the same thing. Either will work :)

Comment: @TylerRadlick just to be more specific, "&&" and "AND" both work in MySQL but "&&" is not ANSI SQL and not supported by most databases.